# How to convert all the datetimes into one standard format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM in csv?

Tags: excel, csv, date, datetime, data-cleaning

There are 2 datetime formats in same column of a csv file. How to convert all the datetimes into one standard format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM/PM?

[a column of the csv having different datetime formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUjgk.png)

Comment: since you're posting this on stackoverflow: do you *have* to do this with Excel? If you had many of these csv tables, using for example a Python script seems more appropriate to me.

Comment: @MrFuppes, Thank  you for the reply. As of now I am intending to do this only in CSV. I would  definitely consider your suggestion on using Python script.

Comment: could you share the CSV here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your dates are in the wrong format. The dd (day-number) and mm (month) are swapped. Only dates with a dd <= 12 are (wrongly) converted, while months with a value > 12 are ignored and treated as text.
Do not open the csv file in a normal way, but import it with the Text Import Wizard (Excel 2016):

1. Create a new file and goto Data -> Get External Date -> From Text
2. Import the csv file
3. In step 2 choose the correct delimiter (probably Comma or Semicolon)
4. In step 3 select the first column in the Data preview and choose Date with the format MDY (not DMY!)

Now the dates will be converted correctly.

5. Select the column with the dates
6. Now go to the Format Cells window by clicking the small arrow button in the bottom-right corner of the Alingment area on the Home tab. Select the date format you want.